# Does OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE work the same for Update and Insert?

Tags: android-room

We have the following legacy code

```kotlin
interface BaseDao<T> {
  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
  fun insertOrReplace(data: T): Single<Long>

  @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
  fun update(data: T): Single<Long>

}
```

Do the functions would achieve the same results?
While I'm sure what `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)` based on my general SQL knowledge

- Replace/ update records if found
- Insert records if not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update will not insert records (rows) not found if you code or omit `OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE`. Update can only act upon rows that exist as per

> It is not an error if the WHERE clause does not evaluate to true for any row in the table - this just means that the UPDATE statement affects zero rows. https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html